# Bootstrap 4 - toggle button changes ">" and "<" icons based on (active) state

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

How can I show an icon to the right side of the button, e.g. ">" or "<", based on the active state of a Bootstrap 4 button? The application is Angular based.

The standard Bootstrap toggle button looks like:

```
<p>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Text plus <!-- either icon ">"or "<" is shown
  </button>
</p>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
  <div class="card card-body">
    Some text down here.
  </div>
</div>
```

So in the normal state the button shows "Text plus '>' (icon)".
When toggled into the active state, the button shows "Text plus '<' (icon)".

I have seen solutions that have the two icons just listed within the .... That does not work (anymore).

Comment: Or you could just use `<ng-container *ngIf="...">&lt;</ng-container>` or even `{{ ... ? '<' : '>' }}`?

Comment: Please show me (laat maar zien ;-)). Zou mooi zijn wanneer dat kan.

Comment: Zoiets? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xuckkf?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Nice solution (leuke creatieve oplossing). Notice that the click event is handled by the bootstrap code to collapse the collapsable part. So, you have to find a way to intercept the click without interfering with the default behaviour of the collapse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. Demo**

Show the Toggle button:

[image]

Click on the button:

[image]

**2. Install the following packages:**

> ```
> $ npm install bootstrap --save
> $ npm install jquery --save
> $ npm install popper.js --save
> ```

**3. Add packages to e.g. Angular (angular.json)**

```
> "styles": [      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css", 
> "styles.css" ], 

> "scripts": [    
>    "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",  
>    "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",  
>    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" ],
```

**4. Template:**

```css
[aria-expanded="true"] .fa-chevron-circle-up,
[aria-expanded="false"] .fa-chevron-circle-down {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" 
      data-target="#collapseNEWS" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseNEWS">
    Text plus icon
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-up"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down"></i>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse" id="collapseNEWS">
    <div class="card card-body">
      Some text down here.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**5. Code**

No Component code needed.